How to give credit for partial scripts used in my code?
I've used full work/libraries written by other people in the past, and it's quite easy: respect the attribution as asked.
The work I think of is actually a codepen, no mention of attribution in the code, no comment, nothing specifically asked. I've tested the code, found it useful, and have modified it. A lot. Basically, I kept 15% (tops), and wrote my own scripts.
It's a website for a sports association (NPO) and I do this pro bono, it's a small shop online for their (tee-)shirts (1 page, 1 cart, 1 checkout, 1 contact, 1 about us). I needed a simple shopping cart (based on localStorage, no DB), I found a model on codepen. I've used the idea, a couple of lines/functions, but modified the core of the script(s). Nevertheless, I did gain some valuable time (and ideas) for sure.
I think like tagging my work as: "Based on xxx" or "Inspired by xxx". Is there good practice/etiquette for this and how credit shall be given?

Please edit tags as I couldn't find some fitting the question, did my best on that...

It is personal preference.  For all my websites, I have an attribution page.
I generally have two categories.

Products/Resources that I have paid for and I have used
Products/Resources that are free and I have used in part or wholly.

For each link,

I provide one sentence stating how I have used it.
I make them nofollow


I was thinking about credit in the source, the js file probably, because there are only 5 pages and very few external resources, but I'll keep your idea in mind. The problem is the wording too, as I wanted to do it based on the usefulness of the idea/script

Yep, either an attributions page or a terms and/or conditions page. @OldPadawan you mention Local Storage and a cart/checkout process, therefore I assume there's some data submission happening, so you will need some terms and a privacy policy as well ;)

@Zhaph-BenDuguid: Yep. The terms/conditions and RGPD are mandatory, they're just a .txt included and loaded with the page. You suggest adding that credit somewhere there?
